# Как сейчас поживает венгерская нотация?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

Помнится в начале существования Windows компания Микрософт сильно продвигала так называемую венгерскую нотацию. Также многие программистские фирмы педалировали это средство как панацею от всех проблем разработки.

Вопрос - что у нас сейчас с венгерской нотацией? Умерла, не умерла? Как к ней относится сама компания Микрософт? Есть какие-нибудь официальные/неофициальные рекомендации?

UPD1:

Тут коллеги все сводят к тому, что венгерская нотация позволяет в имени переменной иметь тип переменной. Но это не совсем так. Если кому-то надо иметь в имени переменной тип этой переменной, то это решается очень просто. Надо просто в имя переменной включать тип переменной. Не просто "a", а "a_int". Венгерская же нотация претендовала на некое описание функционала вызова. Особенно это касается функций WinAPI и MFC. Вот и получалось GetDataFromPromDromStrem и это только самое приличное. Забор из строчных и прописных букв, который якобы облегчал сопровождение программы. Прошло не так много лет и кажется, что даже микрософт не вспоминает об этой поделке.

UPD2:

> Тут я озадачился и пошел в русскую википедию. Нет, там про это ничего
>   не слышали.

Тут уже я озадачился и пошел в русскую википедию. Да, и там про это что-то слышали.

> Префиксы, задающие смысл
>   Венгерская нотация для приложений:
>
> ```
> Префикс Сокращение от   Смысл                    Пример   
> i       index           Индекс                   int ix; Array[ix] = 10;     
> d       delta           Разница между значениями int a, b; ... dba = b - a;  
> n       number          Количество               size_t nFound = 0;  
> a       argument        Аргумент                 SomeClass::SomeClass(int aX) : x(aX) {}
> ```

Вот тут слишком умный форматер на сайте SO удаляет пробелы в строке, поэтому таблицу перенести не удается. Но можно поглядеть в русской википедии.

Вобщем никто не скажет, что delta или number это тип переменной. Это как раз не тип, а функционал переменной. Далее этот подход был перенесен на вызовы в WinAPI и там в каждом имени вызова пытались всунуть функционал этого вызова.

Comment: Я использую только для контролов в winforms. Тем более, что несколько может называться одинаково и отличаться только этим префиксом - например, label и textbox). В остальных местах - нет.

Comment: Венгерская нотация потрясающая вещь, когда употребляется правильно. Рекомендую всем интересующимся: [Making Wrong Code Look Wrong](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2005/05/11/making-wrong-code-look-wrong/) - прочесть следует всю статью, а собственно про саму "венгерку" в конце.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov Статья 2005 года однако.

Comment: Есть перевод статьи на русский: [Как заставить неправильный код выглядеть неправильно](http://local.joelonsoftware.com/wiki/Как_заставить_неправильный_код_выглядеть_неправильно). Не знаю, насколько он хорош.

Comment: Да, изначально было несколько префиксов, указывающих на смысл. Но они оказались малополезными, и сама MS их не использует. Специализированные переменные для индексов - большая редкость. То же самое для дельты, сколько их, чтобы вводить специальный префикс. Аргументы тоже нет смысла выделять, префикс типа в них гораздо полезнее. Остался только префикс `n`, вот только он реально и используется. Мысль задавать префиксом назначение переменной изначально была глупой идеей, назначение не поддается разумной классификацией. Поэтому эта идея и не выжила. Не прошла проверки временем, так сказать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Могу выразить только свое личное мнение - вряд ли существует какая-то официальная позиция даже у MS. Это все-таки не какая-то глобальная вещь мирового масштаба, а всего лишь один из многих способов именования переменных.

Так вот, венгерская нотация это замечательная вещь. Она действительно улучшает сопровождаемость программы. Понимание того, что представляет из себя переменная, очень помогает разобраться в программе. Но если для C ее безусловно можно советовать, в случае C++ дело обстоит сложнее. При активном применении библиотек классов и шаблонов (и стандартной библиотеки в частности) венгерской нотации начинает не хватать. Как нужно называть `shared_ptr<unordered_map<unsigned, string>>`? Загадка.

Даже с обычными строками нотация чрезмерно разрастается. Обычная строка это `sz`. Широкая пусть `wsz`. Как быть с указателями на строки? Ну давайте назовем их `psz` и `pwsz`. А как быть с массивами символов без завершающего нуля? Чувствуется, что ситуация уже начинает выходить из под контроля. Потом вдруг оказывается, что нам еще нужны `char32_t` строки и все окончательно валится под откос.

В результате оказывается, что в программе на C++ тривиальных переменных не так уж много, и они большей частью не стоят того, чтобы именовать их с префиксами. Лично я использую временами эту нотацию в простейших случаях вроде `nItems`, `hFile`, или `szMessage`, но в целом эта нотация для C++ малополезна.

**UPDATE**

Услышал я удивительную вещь, что венгерская нотация это, оказывается, не префикс типа, а просто осмысленное именование в кэмел формате. То есть названия вроде `OpenClipboard` или `CreateNamedPipe` это как раз венгерская нотация и есть. Но начинающие программисты не понимают глубокую идею и сводят все к префиксу типа.

Тут я озадачился и пошел в русскую [википедию](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F). Нет, там про это ничего не слышали. Наверное, начинающие программисты статью писали. Пошел в [английскую](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) - то же самое. Открыл гугл, набрал "hungarian notation" - везде про типы. Microsoft, как выяснилось, тоже все [неправильно пишет](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/dc0e7d00-61f5-4745-8df4-f2f9238af5ea/camel-or-hungarian-notation?forum=csharpgeneral). Беда...

**UPDATE 2**

На тему того, что Правильная Венгерская Нотация относится к назначению переменной, а не к ее типу. Да, первоначально была попытка использовать ее именно в такой форме, но выглядело это откровенно жалко. Слишком много вещей обозначаются переменными, и трудно выделить часто используемые. Ну разве что переменные цикла, да и то они `i, j, k` еще со времен Фортрана 66.

Индекс массива - да я и не вспомню, пожалуй, ни одного случая, когда для индекса массива выделялась бы отдельная переменная. Куда ни глянь, в квадратных скобках либо выражение, либо переменная цикла. Сразу видно, что этот префикс кто-то из себя вымучивал ради галочки.

Да, разность координат естественно назвать `dx` или `dy`, но для этого не надо изобретать специальный префикс. Это естественное имя, как и переменная цикла `i`.
То же самое для `rowFirst` и `colName` - похоже на венгерскую, но формализовать это явно нет смысла.

Так что давайте разделять - есть формальная венгерская нотация, где префикс обозначает именно тип переменной, и есть какие-то псевдовенгерские вариации. Ну вот, например, пишу я в программе

```
loaded_scripts loadedGlobalScripts;
loaded_scripts loadedFileScripts;
loaded_scripts loadedUserScripts;
```

это так называемая Camel нотация. Но вот если бы таких переменных было бы много разных, и они много где использовались, то я бы давал имена в форме `scriptCurrent`, `scriptLastLoaded`, `scriptSpawned` и т.п. Похоже на венгерскую нотацию, но формализовать это невозможно, потому что список таких префиксов просто невозможно было бы выучить.

Заявления, что мол MS испортили такую замечательную Настоящую Венгерскую Нотацию - это полная ерунда. Они ее спасли. Они отбросили первоначальную совершенно нежизнеспособную идею и на ее основе формализовали то, что могло быть формализовано.

P.S. Насчет статьи из комментариев. Джоэль много чего пишет, но не надо относиться к нему как светочу абсолютной истины. Сомнительных утверждений у него хватает, и эта статья хороший пример.

Comment: _Обычная строка это sz. Широкая пусть wsz._ - за это расстреливать надо. Это **не** венгерская нотация. Вернее, первоначально венгерка означало совсем другое, но потом ее стали использовать именно для обозначения _типа_ переменных. Прочитайте статью, на которую я дал ссылку.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov, возможно вы понимаете под венгерской нотацией что-то более возвышенное, но зачем сразу уж расстреливать. Если есть что сказать по теме - не стесняйтесь, жмите кнопку "Ответ".

Comment: Да что тут понимать - венгерская нотация подсказывает сущность переменной. Но для начинающих программистов сущность переменной - это ее тип. А для тех, что понял тему, венгерская нотация - это способ метить предназначение переменной. Почему так возникло? да просто в нормальном коде типы так сделаны, что они несут сущность. К примеру, есть строка, которая хранит пользовательский ввод - ее тип "UserInputString". А есть, строка, которую можно сохранить в базу, у нее тип SafeString. Напрямую типы не кастятся. дальше думаю понятно

Comment: @KoVadim, похоже мы с вами под венгерской нотацией действительно понимаем разные вещи. Я ее понимаю в смысле MS, то есть префикс, показывающий большей частью именно тип. И в этом смысле ни "UserInputString", ни "SafeString" не венгерская нотация, а просто осмысленные названия.

Comment: Вы частично правы. Я привел имена типов. А префиксы для переменных этих типов будут скорее всего u и s. Да, без указания, что это строка.

Comment: Мы сейчас живем в то время, когда `правильно спроектированное` и `прибыльное` - разные вещи. Отсюда вытекает скорость рождения кода, и минимум мыслей о его дальнейшей поддержке, в основном сейчас востребованны сиюминутные вещи, о которых завтра мало кто вспомнит. И весь ваш труд в основном будет листать Аватарки в телефоне или назойливо всовывать рекламу в разные части экрана закрывая привычные элементы управления :) по этому - не актуально сейчас писать красивый и правильный код, актуально чтобы код приносил прибыль сегодня и сейчас..

Comment: @NewView [актуально чтобы код приносил прибыль сегодня и сейчас] В этом и заключена высшая справедливость. Нужен востребованный обществом результат, а не красивый и "правильный" код.

Comment: Это влияние времени, не более, с таким подходом в этой сфере скоро все останутся без работы. Такой код может воять другой софт :) самостоятельно. К экспериментам в этой области уже приступили, + платформы типа MS.Core, вход на собственный компьютер с учётной записи микрософт! итд. В скором времени уберут всяческие прямые API к системе, оставят нечто загружаемое из облака, с API к кнопкам :) и будут брать ежемесячно плату за пользование ОС. Вот к этому все идёт, вернее ведут. Вы не сильно нужны тому лысеещему кортавому старичку, которого почему-то называют ТОП манагер :) хотя слово 'ДНО' лучше.

Comment: @KoVadim, я "частично прав"? Хех, ну спасибо хоть на этом, все какой-то сдвиг. Осталось совсем немного - убедить вас, что венгерская нотация - это исключительно префиксы типов в именах переменных, а имена собственно типов и функций к венгерской нотации никакого отношения не имеют. Не знаю, правда, как это сделать, первоисточники вы явно читать не хотите.

Comment: @freim Не нужно меня убеждать. Это префиксы типов, никто же не спорит. Но не префиксы, которые указывают, что это целая переменная или широкая строка. Но даже сам автор венгерской нотации говорил, что его методику в Майкрософте и испортили. Хотя он ею в свое время спас ворд и эксель

Comment: @KoVadim, "методика" это слишком громкое название для в сущности достаточно второстепенной вещи. Вот сейчас венгерская нотация практически не используется - и что, небо рухнуло, отрасль в застое? Просто некое соглашение для удобства разработки, в большом проекте таких явных и неявных соглашений не одно. А что касается "не указывать широкую строку" - я всегда считал, что венгерская нотация не библия, если изменение или дополнение улучшит читаемость, то тут даже думать не надо. Но тут вы вправе не согласиться, конечно. "Спас ворд и эксель" - это он так рассказывает? :-D

Comment: Да, в так в книге читал. Там к примеру, в экселе складывали строки и столбцы. А добавление префикса, который обозначал переменные, хранящие номера строк и столбцов и их разницу сразу позволял увидеть в коде глупости.