# Использовать ли префиксы в именах переменных?

Tags: c++, c, code-style

Изучаю я WinApi и почти все структуры определяются так:

```cpp
typedef struct tagWNDCLASSEXW {
    UINT        cbSize;
    UINT        style;
    WNDPROC     lpfnWndProc;
    int         cbClsExtra;
    int         cbWndExtra;
    HINSTANCE   hInstance;
    HICON       hIcon;
    HCURSOR     hCursor;
    HBRUSH      hbrBackground;
    LPCWSTR     lpszMenuName;
    LPCWSTR     lpszClassName;
    HICON       hIconSm;
} WNDCLASSEXW, *PWNDCLASSEXW, NEAR *NPWNDCLASSEXW, FAR *LPWNDCLASSEXW;
```

У всех названий полей есть префиксы cb, h, lpsz и т.д.

Используется ли сейчас данный стиль в обычном коде или он устарел?

Comment: Чисто вкусовое решение. Если ваша команда приняла то или иное соглашение об именовании - придерживайтесь его. Если программируете в одиночку - решите сами, как вам удобнее, чтобы было в первую очередь понятно.

Comment: Это называется венгерской нотацией. В Википедии есть статья.

Comment: Дубликат: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/925770/

Comment: Правильно написали о соглашении, но лично я не вижу смысла в современном C++ так писать, когда есть шаблоны и все типы скрываются за `auto`. Переменные должны отображать логику программы, а не детали реализации. Если вдруг вы захотите поменять тип переменной, то придётся и префикс в её названии менять, что не есть хорошо

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight вопрос по ссылке: "Как *сейчас* поживает венгерская нотация?", а задан больше года назад

Comment: примите ответ если он вам помог — галочка слева от ответа

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica так я принял вроде

Comment: @timur Ой, сорри , это я другому участнику хотел написать,перепутал табы.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сейчас поживает венгерская нотация?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/925770/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b9%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b3%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f)

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin `Вопрос задан 1 год 7 месяцев назад`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это называется венгерской нотацией. Её суть в том, чтобы добавлять префиксы в зависимости от типа или смысла какого-либо имени (переменной/поля/типа/…).

Плюсы:

1. В имени отображается тип/смысл именуемого, что при неявном апкасте всего и вся можно сложить не то с не тем, например, указатель с символом.
2. Является контейнером с универсальными и устоявшимися сокращениями

Минусы:

1. Ухудшает читаемость (субъективно)
2. Современные текстовые редакторы нативно отображают тип именуемого и могут очень быстро перемещаться по коду, что ставит под сомнение 1-й плюс
3. Есть альтернатива: добавление ключевых слов, по типу is, can, index, -s, и т. д. В отличие от префиксов они достаточно органично вписываются в имя (`Succeeded` → `IsSucceeded`, `Number` → `Numbers` (массив)).

Венгерская нотация достаточно субъективна, чтобы сказать, что её необходимость определяете конкретно вы/ваша команда.

---

Лично я не использую венгерскую нотацию – использую альтернативу из минуса #3: мне этого вполне хватает. Думаю, можно назвать переменную нормально, чтобы её понимали все и без всяких префиксов (я согласен с актуальностью минуса #1). Т. е. я согласен со всеми (указанными выше) минусами венгерской нотации.

---

В WinAPI она используется, по причине неактуальности минуса #2: WinAPI писалось давно, и тогда не было современных текстовых редакторов – венгерская нотация стала для разработчиков из Microsoft панацеей. Можно заметить, что в современных разработках от Microsoft венгерская нотация (за редким исключением) не используется. Самый яркий пример, это C# и .NET: минус #2 актуален, а плюс #1 не имеет смысла. Следовательно, если уже говорить о венгерской нотации, то вопрос там (C#, .NET) стоит 1: использовать ли альтернативу из минуса #3 (нужно заметить, что у Microsoft по этому поводу однозначного мнения нет ([`IAsyncResult.IsCompleted`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iasyncresult.iscompleted?view=netcore-3.1), [`Socket.Connected`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.connected?view=netcore-3.1))).

Answer (score 0):

У всех по разному, но я расскажу как у нас.

1. Запрещается менять стиль написания программы.
2. Если используется Венгерская нотация то она такой и останется.
3. Код пишется так что не определишь чей либо почерк. Имена переменных, классов, модулей ... придерживаютя стиля заложенного в самом начале. Счастье если оно было заложено грамотно в самом начале.

Answer (score -9):

Ответ от Harry:

Чисто вкусовое решение. Если ваша команда приняла то или иное соглашение об именовании - придерживайтесь его. Если программируете в одиночку - решите сами, как вам удобнее, чтобы было в первую очередь понятно.

Comment: скопировать чужой комментарий как свой ответ, не может для меня не служить поводом для отрицательного голоса...